# How do I find my Django install within my virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have installed Django within a virtual environment but when I call the package, it doesn't show up.

```
$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB): 7.4MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

How do I find my Django install within my virtual environment?

Comment: have you activated your virtual environment? `source bin/activate` on mac and `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate` on windows...

Comment: Is the `enter code here` a part of the error message or left over from pasting in the code here?

Comment: Yes, I took out the name but I do have it activated.

Comment: do you see django when you do `pip list`?

Comment: (venv)-MacBook-Pro:my_project_folder j$ pip list
Django (1.7.1)
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (3.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)

Comment: you may try      pip freeze     to see if the package is there?

Comment: Yes, it is listed if I do a pip freeze.  :    Django==1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` extends/overrides your system python environment with it's paths prepended to the paths of the system python installation.You see, you `.virtualenv` site-packages are listed before the system `site-packages`, that's how it works.

The thing you have to keep in mind that activate patches your current command line environment, so you must run `activate` before running python code depending on your `virtualenv`.

Updated:

The workaround is .. !

```
simon@ri-desktop:~$ mkdir test
simon@ri-desktop:~$ cd test/
simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ ls
simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ virtualenv env
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ ls
env
simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ source env/bin/activate
(env)simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ ls
env
(env)simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ mkdir project
(env)simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ ls
env  project
(env)simon@ri-desktop:~/test$ cd project/
(env)simon@ri-desktop:~/test/project$
```

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, run activate?  This is the response:  (my_project_folder)MacBook-Pro:my_project_folder j$ activate
-bash: /Users/j/Desktop/my_project_folder/bin/activate: Permission denied

Comment: I went through your steps but this time I got an import error.  `(env)MacBook-Pro:test j$ ls
env project
(env)MacBook-Pro:test j$ cd project

(env)MacBook-Pro:project j$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB): 7.4MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
(env)MacBook-Pro:project j$ import django
-bash: import: command not found `

Comment: That's not the correct way to check django. First enter `python` then enter `import django` .. Like that only .. Got it ?

Comment: That seems to make things work inside of the shell but when I do: `python import django` I am still getting `(env)-MacBook-Pro:project j$ python import django 
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`